Apache mod_rewrite How to strip slash off document root AND all URIs
I have apache-2.4.59 on fedora40 and trying to strip any trailing slash(es) from the root and any other URIs using RewriteCond/RewriteRule in my vhost config. I've tried a dozen different combinations of rewritecond and rewriterule but they always create a redirect loop for the document root URI because once the trailing slash is removed, it matches the same pattern, or the .htaccess in the document root starts the rewrite rules again.
Google Search Console interprets the document root with a trailing slash and without a trailing slash as two separate documents, creating confusion about duplicated content.
I've tried a simple rewrite rule that should match any URI with one or more slashes then redirects to that URI without the slash.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ https://example.com$1 [R=301,L]

It works fine for any URL other than the homepage. Somehow for the homepage it creates an infinite loop. The (.*) is supposed to match any character, but there wouldn't be any preceding elements for the homepage.
The problem as I see it is that, for the homepage, (.*) would be null, so $1 would also be null? This then creates the same URL as the one we're trying to fix.
First it appears to work properly (trimmed for legibility):
init rewrite engine with requested uri /
applying pattern '^(.*)/+$' to uri '/'
rewrite '/' -> 'https://linuxsecurity.com'
explicitly forcing redirect with https://linuxsecurity.com
escaping https://linuxsecurity.com for redirect
redirect to https://linuxsecurity.com [REDIRECT/301]

then it looks like it inits the rewrite engine again?
init rewrite engine with requested uri /, referer: https://linuxsecurity.com/
applying pattern '^(.*)/+$' to uri '/', referer: https://linuxsecurity.com/
rewrite '/' -> 'https://linuxsecurity.com', referer: https://linuxsecurity.com/
explicitly forcing redirect with https://linuxsecurity.com, referer: https://linuxsecurity.com/
escaping https://linuxsecurity.com for redirect, referer: https://linuxsecurity.com/
redirect to https://linuxsecurity.com [REDIRECT/301], referer: https://linuxsecurity.com/

This just loops repeatedly until it dies. I've also made sure there's only one "RewriteEngine on" in the virtual host config and the .htaccess. Would that even matter?
I then got the idea to use the REDIRECT_STATUS flag, thinking that it would only process this rule if it was the first time through.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=302,L]

However, it also creates an infinite loop. There are countless examples of RewriteRule and RewriteCond that strip the trailing slash off a URI but none apparently consider a slash on the document root. Please help me create one that works for the document root and any other URI on the HTTP_HOST.

"then it looks like it inits the rewrite engine again?" - you redirected, so the browser is making a completely new request. Of course your rewrite configuration is gone through again now for this new request.

What you intend to do here, doesn't make much sense - at least not for the root URL. An HTTP request has the basic form "[method/verb] [url path] [protocol version]" - and the path can not be left "empty". Any client has to request at least the root path /, otherwise it could not form an HTTP request that was syntactically valid to begin with.

And what browsers display in the address bar, is not necessarily what they are actually requesting. Some browsers might show only http://example.com in the address bar, without the trailing slash - but rest assured, the actual request they will be making, is for the path /.

I do understand they are requesting the root path. The problem I have is that link and link both go to the same page, which creates a duplicate content problem for Google and GSC.  @CBroe

Then I'd specify the proper canonical URL - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel#canonical
